# What are the effects of the Lightning, Laser and Rainbow Pickaxes?

Tags: pickcrafter

Recently, there were added some new rare pickaxes to the game: The Laser, the Lightning and the Rainbow pickaxes.
*I've searched the Wiki, but there is no info on these new Pickaxes.* **What are their effects?**

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Pickaxe power text for each of new pickaxes:

- Lightning Pickaxe : Thunder Clap - Burst of lightning causing an explosion of blocks
- Rainbow Pickaxe : Rainbow Madness - Vastly increases the Picks you gain from picking
- Laser Pickaxe : Triple Beam - Tap and hold to unleash your overloaded laser